# WPF issue with updating

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, binding, mvvm-light

I have a strange issue. I wonder whether it's a standard behavior of the .NET components, and how to handle this.
Our app is using galasoft mvvm light. I have a form with a tree view, which is getting the data via an asynchronous call. And why that asynchronous task is running, we're showing a progress bar to the user. I'm using ObservableCollection as a collection for my tree structure. Now the problem:

This piece of code gives us the info:

```
public Task<ObservableCollection<FillingTreeNode>> GetTreeStructureAsync(SyncSettings settings)
    {
        SearchRequest request = BuildRequest();
        return searchService.SearchRecordsAsync(request).ContinueWithConversion(
            records => new ObservableCollection<FillingTreeNode>(records
            .Select(cabinet => new FillingTreeNode
            {
                IsChecked = false,
                DisplayName = cabinet.Fields[Fields.CabinetName].Value,
                Node = cabinet.AsFillingNode(FillingNodeType.Cabinet),
                NumberOfNodes = SendXmlRequest(record),
                Children = new ObservableCollection<FillingTreeNode>(GetChildren (record));
    }
```

}

This is the task extension to convert the result to some new type:

```
        public static Task<TNew> ContinueWithConversion<TOld, TNew>(this Task<TOld> task, Func<TOld, TNew> conversionAction)
    {
        return task.ContinueWith(completedTask => conversionAction(task.Result));
    }
```

Now the issue. The data is loaded from the server, the UI (the progress bar) says that the data is loaded, and only after that SendXmlRequest(record) (which is a bit long to wait) begins to work! But i expect that it's already done. The user sees nothing until those functions are finished working 
Do you know what is the cause of the problem? Can that be the behavior of the Observable collection? How can i fix it?
Thank in advance.

Comment: Is your SendXmlRequest synchronous method that connects to server?

Comment: Yes it is synchronous. I was debugging, and found that it's running in the same thread, where the tree structure was loaded. The problem is that the Task say "RanToCompletion".

Comment: Does it rub on UI thread? You should show progress even while SendXmlRequest is executing

Comment: The UI thread is living its own way. The task finished, the UI has unblocked the element i blocked for the time the data is loaded, and only after that SendXmlRequest begins to work! That's my problem.

Comment: My guess would relate not to ObservableCollection, but rather to the Select statement + the implementation of the enumerator on the record set returned. If I understand your code right, you do an asynchronous call to fetch the records and then when that async call is "completed" (it has dispatched to the other thread), you continue with trying to populate your tree. What is the type of task.Result? Does it allow the enumerable to be opened on a partially loaded data set, or does it block until all data is loaded? I think most enumerables would block to avoid ending edge cases.

Comment: IMHO it could be a problem that is related to data binding. From what I understand the items are added to a new collection and not added to the collection that drives the update of the progress bar.